# In magento admin url, the word "admin" occurs twice. how to remove the second one?

Tags: php, magento, url

I have a situation where my client's admin url is something like this;

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/0981a6bd2f5a06fec85d3c9e297849a0/
```

the word admin occurs twice, how to remove one. i checked app/etc/local.xml and in magento admin->system->configuration->admin, there was no changes in the default setting.

Comment: Check if you have properly given base url for the default store, i.e it doesn't contain admin in the URL

Comment: @HashidHameed if you are pointing to System->Configuration->web->secure/unsecure-baseurl, then no, they don't contain admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on [magento.stack](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/41234/in-magento-admin-url-the-word-admin-occurs-twice-how-to-remove-the-second-on) and thanks to @Marius for pointing the issue in no time.
In magento admin->System->Configuration->Web, "Use Store Codes in URL" was set to "yes" which was causing this problem.